# Nested JSON output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, ezsql

I'm building an API for an iOS app and trying to get the mySQL data into a JSON string for processing. The desired output would require top level order details like customer name and address and then a sub array of products ordered.

There are quite a few fields in both tables i need and it i'm hoping to have all fields. I've built a script to do this, but the output is reporting as malformed in a JSON validator.

Here's my code:

```
$orders = $db->get_results("SELECT ords.serial as ID, cust.title, cust.name, cust.surname, cust.address, cust.address2, cust.town, cust.county, cust.postcode, cust.phone, cust.height, cust.weight, cust.houseType, cust.parking, cust.access, ords.furnitureRem, ords.furnitureRemDetails, ords.comments FROM orders as ords JOIN customers as cust ON ords.customerid = cust.serial JOIN order_detail as odeet ON ords.serial = odeet.orderid JOIN `user` as us ON us.id = ords.user_id  WHERE us.id='".$_REQUEST['userID']."' GROUP BY ords.serial ORDER BY cust.serial DESC"); 

$json_response = array(); //Create an array
foreach ( $orders as $row )
{
    $row_array = array();
    $row_array[] = $row;        
    $ord_id = $row->ID;  

    $orders2 = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM order_detail as ord
    JOIN products as prod ON ord.productid = prod.id
    WHERE ord.orderid = ".$ord_id);
    foreach ( $orders2 as $vorder2 ) {
    {
        $row_array['products'][] = $vorder2;
    }
    array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
}
```

The current output is like this:

[image]

Here's the RAW output, by request:

```
[{"0":{"ID":"756","title":"Mr","name”:”John”,”surname”:”Smith”,”address”:”Address Line 1”,”address2”:”Address Line 2”,”town”:”Town","county”:”County”,”postcode”:”PO57 8DE”,”phone":"0777777777777”,”height":"6ft","weight":"14st","houseType":"Flat","parking":"none","access":"No problems","furnitureRem":"0","furnitureRemDetails":null,"comments":null},"products":[{"orderid":"756","productid":"2","price":"6500","status":"1","id":"2","type":"Chair","style":"Surrey","action":"Single Motor 2 Way Tilt in Space","weightCap":"35st","height":"14\"","width":"24\"","internalWidth":null,"length":null,"internalLength":null,"depth":"16\"","fabric":"Leather","fabricCode":"LR43","backStyle":"Waterfall","cushionFabric":"Leather","cushionFabricCode":"LR43","backHeight":"32\"","armHeight":"7\"","seatingOptions":"Memory Foam","armOption":"Scrolled","backupBattery":"2x Backup","headRoll":"1","headCover":"1","seatCover":"0","armCover":"0","armCap":"1","pocket":"Left","loop":"Left","antimacassar":"0","freedom":"1","heatMassage":"0","castorsGlides":"Castors","footPlate":"0","seatDepthAdj":"0","doorFrame":null,"additionalCover":"0","scViscoform":"0","scPommelViscoform":"0","scLiquiform":"0","scPommelLiquiform":"0","scCelliform":"0","scAirform":"0","scDynaform":"0","bsWaterfall":"0","bsComfortLateral":"0","bsProfileWaterfall":"0","bsProfileComfortLateral":"0","bsSupportLateral":"0","bsProfileSupportLateral":"0","hsLargeProfileHeadrest":"0","hsSmallHeadPillow":"0","hsSmallProfileHeadPillow":"0","hsMidlineHeadrest":"0","woodColour":"0","frameColour":null,"baseColour":null,"headFootBoard":null,"mattressType":null,"productHeightLowest":null,"productHeightHighest":null,"liftingPoles":null,"grabRails":null,"readingLight":"0","existingBedHeight":null,"legHeight":null,"drawerOptions":null,"hoistCutouts":"0","cotSides":null,"liftingPole":"0","sideRetention":"0","linked":"0","rrp":null,"stock":"0"}]}][{"0":{"ID":"756","title":"Mr","name":"John","surname":"Smith","address":"Address Line 1","address2":"Address Line 2","town":"Town","county":"County","postcode":"PO57 8DE","phone":"0777777777777","height":"6ft","weight":"14st","houseType":"Flat","parking":"none","access":"No problems","furnitureRem":"0","furnitureRemDetails":null,"comments":null},"products":[{"orderid":"756","productid":"2","price":"6500","status":"1","id":"2","type":"Chair","style":"Surrey","action":"Single Motor 2 Way Tilt in Space","weightCap":"35st","height":"14\"","width":"24\"","internalWidth":null,"length":null,"internalLength":null,"depth":"16\"","fabric":"Leather","fabricCode":"LR43","backStyle":"Waterfall","cushionFabric":"Leather","cushionFabricCode":"LR43","backHeight":"32\"","armHeight":"7\"","seatingOptions":"Memory Foam","armOption":"Scrolled","backupBattery":"2x Backup","headRoll":"1","headCover":"1","seatCover":"0","armCover":"0","armCap":"1","pocket":"Left","loop":"Left","antimacassar":"0","freedom":"1","heatMassage":"0","castorsGlides":"Castors","footPlate":"0","seatDepthAdj":"0","doorFrame":null,"additionalCover":"0","scViscoform":"0","scPommelViscoform":"0","scLiquiform":"0","scPommelLiquiform":"0","scCelliform":"0","scAirform":"0","scDynaform":"0","bsWaterfall":"0","bsComfortLateral":"0","bsProfileWaterfall":"0","bsProfileComfortLateral":"0","bsSupportLateral":"0","bsProfileSupportLateral":"0","hsLargeProfileHeadrest":"0","hsSmallHeadPillow":"0","hsSmallProfileHeadPillow":"0","hsMidlineHeadrest":"0","woodColour":"0","frameColour":null,"baseColour":null,"headFootBoard":null,"mattressType":null,"productHeightLowest":null,"productHeightHighest":null,"liftingPoles":null,"grabRails":null,"readingLight":"0","existingBedHeight":null,"legHeight":null,"drawerOptions":null,"hoistCutouts":"0","cotSides":null,"liftingPole":"0","sideRetention":"0","linked":"0","rrp":null,"stock":"0"}]},{"0":{"ID":"756",""title":"Mr","name":"John","sur...
```

I'm just stumped with this one. Or am I going to need to itemise each field in the dataset for this to output a clean JSON?

Comment: It might help to see the original output in text format, not something that some tool managed to interpret out of it as an image.

Comment: Sure. I'll add it. It was purely for ease of reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that clear from the question, but I think you need something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 123,
    ...
    "products": [
      {
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "foo": "baz"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

If this is right, you need to refactor your code a little bit. First of all, you have to put the `products` array inside the `$row_array` array, which should be `$row`, not contain it. Since `$row` seems to be an object with public properties, you can just cast `$row` to array and assign it to `$row_array`:

```
$row_array = (array) $row;
```

As you can see, no need for a `$row_array` that wraps the `$row`, your `$row_array` should be your `$row`.

In the end, avoid using `array_push()` when you have to push only one element at the end of the array:

```
$json_response[] = $row_array;
```

Is faster than `array_push()`.

The final piece of code you need is just this:

```
$orders = $db->get_results(("SELECT ords.serial as ID, cust.title, cust.name, cust.surname, cust.address, cust.address2, cust.town, cust.county, cust.postcode, cust.phone, cust.height, cust.weight, cust.houseType, cust.parking, cust.access, ords.furnitureRem, ords.furnitureRemDetails, ords.comments FROM orders as ords JOIN customers as cust ON ords.customerid = cust.serial JOIN order_detail as odeet ON ords.serial = odeet.orderid JOIN `user` as us ON us.id = ords.user_id  WHERE us.id='".$_REQUEST['userID']."' GROUP BY ords.serial ORDER BY cust.serial DESC");

$json_response = array();
foreach ( $orders as $row ) {
    $row_array = (array) $row;
    $ord_id = $row->ID;

    $orders2 = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM order_detail as ord
        JOIN products as prod ON ord.productid = prod.id
        WHERE ord.orderid = ".$ord_id);
    foreach ( $orders2 as $vorder2 ) {
        $row_array['products'][] = $vorder2;
    }
    $json_response[] = $row_array;
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. It make much more sense now. I've not seen "$row_array = (array) $row;" used before. I like!

Comment: Since `$row_array` should indeed be `$row`, but `$row` is an object, you can just cast it with `(array)`. I'll update the answer to make it clearer.